# Doing crypto in Solidity

Tags: cryptography, rsa, ethereum, solidity, signature

I having searched the web,
I am unable to find any comprehensive
introduction into the crypto library of
Solidity.
I am most interested in doing asymmetrical decryption / verifying signatures.
But I am unable to find any way short of implementing RSA decryption
myself, to implement such a verification.
And the first rule of cryptography for a programmer is: **Do not implement a cipher yourself**.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the limited execution environment, implementing some crypto libraries in Solidity would be too expensive. Also, there are not many use cases for deciphers outside of built-in ones.